# How can I have my service be the first service to begin stopping on system reboot/shutdown?

Tags: linux, redhat-enterprise-linux, systemd, kubernetes

I am trying to have a custom service shutdown an application on reboot, I can get the service file to work correctly up to a point, that point being that the my custom service needs to be brought down before the network.target goes offline and NFS becomes unmounted. I've tried adding network.target to a Before line in the unit file. Here is what I currently have that all appears to be working except for needing access to the network to issue it's commands to complete successfully. Here is my service file thus far:

```
[Unit]
Description=Kubernetes startup and shutdown
DefaultDependencies=no
Before=remote-fs.target network.target reboot.target shutdown.target halt.target

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c '/root/kube-stop.sh'
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=halt.target shutdown.target reboot.target
```

Does seem I was able to start heading in the right direction by having the sshd service within the 'Before' statement and removing 'RemainAfterExit' as that appears to be more geared towards a oneshot service type:

```
[Unit]
Description=Kubernetes startup and shutdown
DefaultDependencies=no
Before=sshd.service

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c '/root/kube-stop.sh'

[Install]
WantedBy=halt.target shutdown.target reboot.target
```

Comment: You probably want some sort of batch file that stops your service, and then calls the reboot/shutdown option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does seem I was able to start heading in the right direction by having the sshd service within the 'Before' statement and removing 'RemainAfterExit' as that appears to be more geared towards a oneshot service type:

But what you have *is* a oneshot service, as it doesn't start any long-running daemons – it just performs a short task and exits, and that's literally what `Type=oneshot` is for.

Indeed in this case you want *both* `Type=oneshot` and `RemainAfterExit=yes`, because the easiest way to run shutdown commands with complex dependencies is to run them **from `ExecStop=`**.

That is, you should have an `ExecStart=` that does nothing at all (current systemd versions allow you to leave it out completely, for older ones just execute /bin/true), together with `ExecStop=` that actually tells Kubernetes to stop itself. The unit should then simply be started on boot like any other service.

This is because services are stopped on shutdown in pretty much the opposite order as they were started – if your unit needs networking to be available, it should have `After=network.target`, so that it gets started after network, but stopped before network.

```
[Unit]
Description=Kubernetes startup and shutdown
After=network.target
After=kubernetes-or-something.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
# ExecStart=/bin/true
ExecStop=/root/kube-stop.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

(You don't need the `/bin/sh -c ...` unless your command uses shell syntax features. Executing a .sh script is *not* a shell syntax feature.)